# Parsing and setting a date

Tags: java, datetime

I have dates like -

15-JUL-10 00:00:00

12-AUG-10 23:59:59

24-SEP-10 18:13:18

How do I easily parse these sort of dates and assign to a Date object?

Comment: Start from [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a date in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725578/parsing-a-date-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss");
df.parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = fmt.parse("15-JUL-10 00:00:00");
```