# Parsing date to specific format in java

Tags: java, parsing, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing a date in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725578/parsing-a-date-in-java)
>   [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

How can i parse Date object which by default returns this format:

```
Nov 22, 1963 00:00:00 PM
```

to this format:

```
Fri Nov 22 1963 00:00:00 GMT-0600
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Look at the "Related" section at the right of this page, and you'll find dozens of similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use SimpleDateFormat ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html ) class to parse original string, snd after it format it using new format with SimpleDateFormat class.

Comment: There are known concurrency issues with SimpleDateFormat. FastDateFormat is essentially the same only threadsafe

Answer (score 1):

[FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html) is (from their api), "a fast and thread-safe version of SimpleDateFormat."
[Here](http://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/sdf/) is an article that explains it

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have a [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) object from `String` for this you can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), Here is an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/803285) related to this step.

Secondly, you have to get back this `Date` in respective text format, for this again use `SimpleDateFormat` as:

```
Format formatter = new new SimpleDateFormat("your format here");
String dateString = formatter.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
sdfDestination .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-6").getID());
String strDate = sdfDestination.format(oldDateObject); //pass here your old date object
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you phrase your question indicates that you're confusing a number of things.

First of all, you don't "parse a Date object". You can convert a string that contains a date (as text) into a `Date` object. That's what is called **parsing**. So, you parse a **string** and the result is a `Date` object - you don't "parse a Date object".

The opposite (converting a `Date` object into a string) is called **formatting**.

`Date` objects by themselves do not have a format. Just like a number is just a number (it doesn't have an inherent format), a `Date` is just a date. When you call `toString()` (explicitly or implicitly) on a `Date` object, then the date will be printed using some default format that looks like `Nov 22, 1963 00:00:00 PM`. But the format is not a property of the `Date` object itself.

To display a `Date` in a specific format, you can use a `DateFormat` object, to format the date into a string which can then be printed. You specify the exact format in the `DateFormat` object. For example:

```
Date date = new Date();

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
String text = df.format(date);
System.out.println(text);
```