# How to change the base date for parsing two letter years with Java 8 DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, date, parsing, java-time, 2-digit-year

If I use a pattern like `d/M/yy` for creating a Java 8 DateTimeFormatter (e.g. using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);` (which I will only use for parsing, not formatting), it will interpret all two-letter years as 20xx, e.g. parsing a string like `13/5/99` to be interpreted as `2099-05-13`, which in my case is wrong (it was meant to be in the year 1999).

In my application, I'm trying to parse dates from OCR'd documents, which could e.g. still be from the 90ies, so having the old SimpleDateFormat behavior of interpreting the date to be within 80 years before and 20 years after the current date fits me quite well. But for various reasons I'm still looking to switch the whole date parsing logic to the new Java 8 DateTimeFormatters.

Looking through the Java source code, I see that this is all interpreted relative to the constant `ReducedPrinterParser.BASE_DATE`, but I see no way to change the value used when building my own formatter from a pattern. Is this simply not possible or have I missed some possibility of specifying the behavior for parsing two-letter years?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing string to local date doesn't use desired century](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490893/parsing-string-to-local-date-doesnt-use-desired-century)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a custom formatter, for example for the `d/M/yy` pattern:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("d/M/")
        .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2, 2, LocalDate.now().minusYears(80))
```

Example usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
          .appendPattern("d/M/")
          .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2, 2, LocalDate.now().minusYears(80))
          .toFormatter();
  parse("13/5/99", fmt);
  parse("13/5/36", fmt);
  parse("13/5/35", fmt);
  parse("13/5/34", fmt);
  parse("13/5/33", fmt);
}

private static void parse(String date, DateTimeFormatter fmt) {
  System.out.println(date + " = " + LocalDate.parse(date, fmt));
}
```

which prints:

> 13/5/99 = 1999-05-13
>   13/5/36 = 1936-05-13
>   13/5/35 = 1935-05-13
>   13/5/34 = 2034-05-13
>   13/5/33 = 2033-05-13

Comment: A bit cumbersome (since I'll have to basically parse my existing list of patterns, check if it contains "yy" and then build the formatter like you described), but its definitely doable, thanks, I didn't know I could combine a part of a pattern with the other options like that!

Comment: Oh, and a hint for people stumbling upon the same problem: appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2, 4, LocalDate.now().minusYears(80)) gives you the ability to parse both two-character and four-character years!