# Parse date of after 20 years

Tags: java

I have a  string like "1512". I need to convert it to a date 2015-12-31 23:59:59.

In that case, I am using Java Dateformat parse.

My code:

```
private static final dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMM");

public static boolean checkDate(String date){
Date date =  dateformat.parse(date);
}
```

It can give date upto 20 years. When date is "3610", it gives, 1936, instead of 2036 (of the current century).

Comment: So you want to be able to parse a future date? Also, just curious, why do you pick the last possible second of the specified month?

Comment: [Surely nobody in their right mind still thinks its a good idea to write software that handles years as two-digit numbers?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) Can't you afford two extra bytes?

Comment: I am working in ISO 8583 date..The specification says date format is in YYMM format.

Comment: The `Date` class is outdated and badly designed, as is the associated `Calendar` class. It's recommended to manipulate dates and times using `java.time` in Java 8, or Joda Time in earlier versions of Java, and avoid using `Date` except when legacy code mandates it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks for the information, can you point out any discussion related to your point. It will be helpful.

Comment: We cannot use Java 8 in production environment. We need to use Java 7 1.7.51.

Comment: So get the [Joda-Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe so don't reference it statically

Comment: Are you sure, JodaTime can solve the issue? So far I know, JodaTime is also depend on DateFormat. As long as DateFormat being used, it will be the same.

Comment: @rajuGT Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/4125191) for the problems in the old Java Date API.

Comment: @ZakirCSE JodaTime has its own formatting classes, not `DateFormat`. Its [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), for example, allows you to set your own pivot year for two-digit years, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can manually parse the String and then create the `Date` object.

suppose:

```
public static void checkDate(String date) throws ParseException {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(2, 4));
    calendar.setLenient(false);         
    int yearOfCentury = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int century = yearOfCentury - yearOfCentury % 100;
    year = year + century;
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE,             calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,  59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,  59);
    System.out.println("Date +" + calendar.getTime());    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the year should be always 2000+ then prefix the string with "20" manually and use the SimpleDateFormat as

```
private static final dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
```

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year):

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"),
>   SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some
>   century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before
>   and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created.
>   For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a SimpleDateFormat
>   instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be
>   interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string **"05/04/64"** would be
>   interpreted as May 4, **1964**.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of the `YearMonth` parser in Java 8 for 2 digit years is to start from 2000. So this would give you the result you expect:

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse("3610", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMM"));
//ym = 2036-10
```

If you want a cut-off at a specific date (say you want 80-99 to be 1980-1999 and 0-79 to be 2000-2079) you can use [a custom pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505490/how-to-change-the-base-date-for-parsing-two-letter-years-with-java-8-datetimefor).

Comment: we could not use Java 8.