# Java Entity - storing dates

Tags: java, date, jpa

How can I store dates in this format `14-04-2017` in my entities?

But I have to parse it from a String.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    today = dateFormat.parse("2017-04-14");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    //catch exception
}
```

And I get: `Fri Apr 14 00:00:00 CEST 2017`

Comment: and what you expected to get ?

Comment: 14-04-2017 or 2017-04-14

Comment: Use the `SimpleDateFormatter.format` method.

Comment: You probably mean you got `Fri Apr 14 00:00:00 CEST 2017` when you  printed `today`. That would be correct because you actually see `today.toString()` as created by the [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) method of `Date` class.

Comment: There are lot of questions about `SimpleDateFormat` in SO, for instance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725578/parsing-a-date-in-java/1725595#1725595), may I advise to give them a look ?

Comment: Or `LocalDate.toString()` (gives `2017-04-14`).

Comment: What I meant to say was, since you only want the date, not the time, if you can use Java 8, `LocalDate` fits your need better than the outdated `Date` class. You will also want to make sure that your database column holds a date only, not a date and time.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "this format". If you have a Date (field) then it can be stored as a DATE (column). If you want to store them as a String then that is the only place a "format" matters! So define your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

1. import

   ```
   import com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils;
   import java.sql.Timestamp;    
   import java.time.LocalDate;
   import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
   import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
   ```
2. yourObjectModel and yourObjectTO Object

   ```
   @Column(name = "date")
   private Timestamp date;

   private String date;
   ```
3. parse the input

   ```
   if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(yourObjectTO.getDate())) {
       yourObjectModel.setDate(convertStringToTimestamp(yourObjectTO.getDate()));
   }
   ```
4. util method for conversion

   ```
   public static Timestamp convertStringToTimestamp(String strDate) {      
       String format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
       if(strDate.contains("-")) {
           format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
       }
       DateTimeFormatter DATE_TME_FORMATTER =  
           new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern(format)
           .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
           .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
           .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
           .toFormatter();
       LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse(strDate.substring(0, 10), DATE_TME_FORMATTER);
       Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(dt.atStartOfDay());
       return timestamp;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2017-04-14" )
```

## Using java.time

You are using the wrong classes.

Avoid the troublesome old legacy classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`. Now supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

### ISO 8601

Your input happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time classes use those standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2017-04-14" );
```

To generate a string in the same format, call `toString`.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

Do not conflate strings with date-time objects. Date-time objects can be created by parsing a string. Date-time objects can generate strings to represent their value. But the string and the date-time are always separate and distinct.

Your first line in the Question uses a different format. I hope that was a mistake. You should stick with the ISO 8601 formats whenever possible, *especially* when serializing for data exchange.

If you really want other formats, search for `DateTimeFormatter`. Already covered many many times on Stack Overflow.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).