# is there any way to convert the date in java prior to 1970?

Tags: java, java-8, simpledateformat, date-formatting, 2-digit-year

I wanted to convert date in yymmdd format to YYYYMMDD, but when using the simpledateformat class i am getting the years after 1970, but the requirement is of the year which is prior to 1970.

Comment: show what you mean in code?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I believe that there are a couple of helpful answers here: [How to convert two digit year to full year using Java 8 time API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719918/how-to-convert-two-digit-year-to-full-year-using-java-8-time-api) (also when the question isn’t exactly the same).

Comment: Use Java 8 java.time api, older date api is broken.

Comment: Besides using an outdated, discouraged API, is it really that hard to find the `set2DigitYearStart` method in it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I’ll be brutally honest with you, in my view this is a poor question by Stack Overflow standards. It shows no search, research or other effort, it has no code, no minimal example, no example input and output. I know you’re new here, so I have provided an answer anyway. It takes a bit to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please make an effort, and I trust you’ll learn.

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

**Parsing input**

The way to control the interpretation of the 2-digit year in `yymmdd` is through the `appendValueReduced` method of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

```
    DateTimeFormatter twoDigitFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 2, 1870)
            .appendPattern("MMdd")
            .toFormatter();
    String exampleInput = "691129";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(exampleInput, twoDigitFormatter);
```

Supplying a base year of 1870 causes two-digit years to be interpreted in the range 1870 through 1969 (so always prior to 1970). Supply a different base year according to your requirements. Also unless you are sure that input years all across a period of 100 years are expected and valid, I recommend you do a range check of the parsed date.

**Formatting and printing output**

```
    DateTimeFormatter fourDigitFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd");
    String result = date.format(fourDigitFormatter);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output in this example is:

> 19691129

If instead input was `700114`, output is:

> 18700114

**Use LocalDate for keeping your date**

Instead of converting your date from one string format to another, I suggest that it’s better to keep your date in a `LocalDate`, not a string (just like you don’t keep an integer value in a string). When your program accepts string input, parse into a `LocalDate` at once. Only when it needs to give string output, format the `LocalDate` back into a string. For this reason I have also separated parsing from formatting above.

**Link**

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.